# Error producing location values android

Tags: android, xml

I'm building an app that makes use of a users geo-location. The idea is that when they navigate to the DataEntry activity that the app gets the users location and fills a TextView with the String value (converted from the original double lat/lng value). I'm having difficult getting it to work but can't see where I'm going wrong. There's a NullPointerException error when I load the DE.Java activity at the place where I try and get the location. Leading me to believe that the location value has not been initialized but to me it looks like it has!

Here is the relevant code for DE.java

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_entry);

    txtBuildingName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.nameContent);
    txtDescription=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.descriptionContent);

    txtLongitude=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.TextViewLong);
    txtLongitude.setText(getLongitude());

    project=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.type_project);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterTwo = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.type_project_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    project.setAdapter(adapterTwo);
```

And the code for the `getLongitude()` method:

```
     public String getLongitude(){
     LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
     longitude = location.getLongitude();
     String longRes = String.valueOf(longitude); 
     return longRes;
 }
```

Now the app is still in development so for now I have turned on GPS and entered some location values using the telnet connection and the geo fix command at the command line which is why I haven't implemented any checking for `LocationProvider` but I will in future. For now, one can assume GPS is always available.

Below is the prinout of the LOGCAT log:

```
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{application.prototype.mfb/application.prototype.mfb.DataEntry}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at application.prototype.mfb.DataEntry.getLongitude(DataEntry.java:181)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at application.prototype.mfb.DataEntry.onCreate(DataEntry.java:54)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
11-09 14:55:17.301: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  ... 11 more
```

I have added the correct `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and 'ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in the Manifest.XML file as well so that won't be the problem.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this line:

`Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`

location might be null, you have to check for null!

Comment: but how can location be null if I've set the values at the command line using telnet and geofix?

Comment: read the method description: `If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.`

Comment: I'm aware of that but I have enabled GPS Support on the AVD, I have entered some lat/lng values using telnet and geofix and yet it still returns null.

Comment: I've never used the emulator before, and I've used that line before. So I can only assume it's some emulator bug. try testing on a real device.

Comment: Okay thank you! My device is annoyingly at home and not in the office! -_-

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the vm of the sdk as emulator.

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

Then set your position for the emulator via

```
geo fix <longitude value> <latitude value>
```

I've some code on github you can use

https://github.com/billmcnamara/BarcelonaTravelGuide.Android